# Умножение квадратных матриц без использования встроенных функций numpy

Tags: python, массивы

Нужно перемножить две квадратные матрицы:  без использования встроенных функций numpy
вот что получается у меня:

```
for i in range(len(a)):
    for j in range(len(a)):       
        c[i][j] = (a[i][j] * b[i][j])
    print(c, end=' ')
    print()
```

но это умножение не строка на столбец как это нужно, а поэлементное перемножение. Как реализовать перемножение матриц строка на столбец по правилам математики?

Answer (score 4):

```
length = len(first_matrix) 
result_matrix = [[0 for i in range(length)] for i in range(length)]
for i in range(length):
  for j in range(length):
    for k in range(length):
       result_matrix[i][j] += first_matrix[i][k] * second_matrix[k][j]
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 3):

В вашей программе нужно вместо `a[i][j] * b[i][j]` сделать:

- #### сумму всех `a[i][k] * b[k][j]`, где `k` меняется от `0` до `len(a) - 1`.

Перемножить возможно даже *неквадратные* матрицы, когда:

- количество столбцов первой матрицы *то же самое* как количество строк второй матрицы,

значит, когда

- первая матрица (`a`) типа `m × n` (т.е. `m` строк и `n` столбцов), и
- вторая матрица (`b`) типа `n × k`.

(Результатом будет тогда матрица типа `m × k`.)

Я сделал именно такую программу — когда вы хотите это специально только для перемножения квадратных матриц, удалите вторую и третью строку и в остальной части (вместо `n` и `k`) примените только `m`:

```
m = len(a)                                            # a: m × n
n = len(b)                                            # b: n × k
k = len(b[0])

c = [[None for __ in range(k)] for __ in range(m)]    # c: m × k

for i in range(m):
    for j in range(k):       
        c[i][j] = sum(a[i][kk] * b[kk][j] for kk in range(n))
  
print(c)
```

---

*Тест:*

Для матриц `a` (типа `2 × 3`) и `b` (типа `3 × 4`):

```
a = [[1, 1, 0],
     [1, 0, 2]]
     
b = [[1, 0, 2, 1],
     [2, 1, 2, 0],
     [1, 1, 0, 3]]
```

программа выводит как результат (правильный) такую матрицу `c` (типа `2 × 4`):

> ```
> [[3, 1, 4, 1],
>  [3, 2, 2, 7]]
> ```

---

*Примечание 1:*

Для такого красивого вывода я не использовал функцию `print()`, а `pprint()` из стандартного модуля `pprint`:

```
from pprint import pprint

pprint(c, width=15)
```

*Примечание 2:*

Правильность возможно проверить например в NumPy:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.array(a) @ b

array([[3, 1, 4, 1],
       [3, 2, 2, 7]])
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
from typing import List


def vec_product(vec1: List[int], vec2: List[int]) -> int:
    return sum([int(x * y) for x, y in zip(vec1, vec2)])


def matrix_transpose(mat: List[List]) -> List[List]:
    return [*map(list, zip(*mat))]


def matrix_product(mat1: List[List[int]], mat2: List[List[int]]):
    l, n = len(mat1), len(mat2[0])
    ans = [[0 for i in range(n)] for j in range(l)]
    for i in range(l):
        for j in range(n):
            vec1 = mat1[i]
            vec2 = matrix_transpose(mat2)[j]
            ans[i][j] = vec_product(vec1, vec2)
    return ans
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

```
length = len(a) 

c = [[sum(a[i][n] * b[n][j] for n in range(length)) for j in range(length)] for i in range(length)]
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]